# how do I fight/ protect and gather evidence if my router was copy Mac and my Mac was ported?

Tags: mac-address, network-access, bridge, port-forwarding, port-security

I learned recently that my devices including router had it's Mac address copied multiple times. I believe I'm going through a network hacking that uses the Mac addresses to drown my network services. How can I gather the best evidence of this happening where do I look exactly?

Comment: Please add details to your question to why you think that the router's MAC addresses was "copied", your router model and what the problem looks like. As it is, it's hard to make sense of your question. Note that home networking and consumer-grade hardware are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic].

Comment: None of the original question really makes sense. No one would want to copy your router's MAC address unless they are already connected to your local network or simply want to interrupt your internet access by connecting to your ISP connection (also likely in your home). Knowing your MAC address does nothing to allow someone to 'drown' or hack your network in any meaningful way. If you think your internet access is not secure, contact your ISP and ask them to require a username and password on your account or to deauthorize your current MAC address and replace your router. That's about it.